# Pl/Sql using cursors, having problems

Tags: plsql, cursors

I have a problem using a cursor in a pl/sql bloc. I have a table called `Angajati(employees)` and i need to display all the employees from every departament, for example:

```
Dep 10:
      John Smith 
      King Steven
Dep 20:
      Henry King
      William
...
```

When i am trying to do this, i received an error like `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large` or my script is not showing anything. This is my code:

```
declare

dep_min angajati.id_departament %type;

dep_max angajati.id_departament %type;

id_min angajati.id_angajat %type;


id_max angajati.id_angajat %type;

i angajati.id_angajat %type;

cursor c is select nume, prenume, id_departament, id_angajat from angajati where id_angajat=i;

    r c%rowtype;



begin
    select min(id_departament), max(id_departament) into dep_min, dep_max from angajati;
    select min(id_angajat), max(id_angajat) into id_min, id_max from angajati;

    open c;

    loop
    dbms_output.put_line('...');
    dbms_output.put_line('Departamentul ' || dep_min);

    for i in id_min..id_max
    loop

       fetch c into r;

    if(r.id_departament=dep_min) then
      dbms_output.put_line(r.nume || ' ' || r.prenume );
    else null;
    end if;

    exit when id_min>id_max;
    end loop;

    dep_min:=dep_min+10;
    end loop;
    close c;
end;
/
```

Comment: Show your schema for table `angajati(employees)`

Answer (score 0):

To obtain such a result, it is better to use the following:

```
Dep 10:
      John Smith 
      King Steven
Dep 20:
      Henry King
      William
```

PL/SQL code:

```
BEGIN
 FOR dep IN (SELECT id_departament,
                                        COUNT(*) cnt
                             FROM angajati
                            GROUP BY id_departament
                            ORDER BY id_departament) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Dep ' || dep.id_departament || '. Count employee ' || dep.cnt);
        FOR empl IN (SELECT * FROM angajati WHERE id_departament = dep.id_departament) LOOP
             dbms_output.put_line(empl.nume || ' ' || empl.prenume);
        END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer by Stepan this can be done by that simpler way too but if you insist to go via your approach. May be this helps. But this can be done via SQL also. Always prefer SQL over PLSQL whenever possible. I don't have workspace with me now so please pardon any syntactical errors.

```
DECLARE
  dep_min angajati.id_departament%type;
  dep_max angajati.id_departament%type;
  id_min angajati.id_angajat%type;
  id_max angajati.id_angajat%type;
  i angajati.id_angajat%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(id_departament),
    MAX(id_departament)
  INTO dep_min,
    dep_max
  FROM angajati;

  SELECT MIN(id_angajat),
    MAX(id_angajat)
  INTO id_min,
    id_max
  FROM angajati;

  dbms_output.put_line('...');
  dbms_output.put_line('Departamentul ' || dep_min);
  FOR k IN id_min..id_max
  LOOP
    FOR J IN
    (SELECT nume,
      prenume,
      id_departament,
      id_angajat
    FROM angajati
    WHERE id_angajat=i
    )
    LOOP
      IF(j.id_departament=dep_min) THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(j.nume || ' ' || j.prenume );
      ELSE
        NULL;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    dep_min:=dep_min+10;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```